# error - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

to start out preemptively, I've already looked at various similar articles dealing with this, but I still get the error.
I'm starting out on rails and attempting to create a GPA calculator and tracker application for fun (and spent a lot of time searching through documentation); I have a singular controller and view since redirecting to an entire different page for calculating or saving a new GPA every time would look ugly.
Rails will display everything without error up until I add the form, no other erb is written currently, and the form is meant to submit letter grade values from the "f.selection" tag.
The culprit is `@cgpa` in `<%= form_for @cgpa do |f| %>`.

My form from main\index view:

```
<%= form_for @cgpa do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
  (...)
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'Calculate' %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
 def index
  #@cgpa = CurrentGpa.all  #currently calls a key_to error while form exists, otherwise no error is raised
  @pgpa = PastGpa.all
  @csem = CurrentSemester.all
  @psem = PastSemester.all
 end
 def new 
  @cgpa = CurrentGpa.new
 end
 def create
 (...)
 end
end
```

The routes are simply `Rails.application.routes.draw { root 'main#index'; resources :main }`

If any other information is needed, just let me know to add >.>

Comment: Hey, You are calling the form instance from the index method so the new method code should be inside the index method and it will solved your problem.

Comment: Or you can change it like <%= form_for @cgpa do |f| %> to <%= form_for  CurrentGpa.new do |f| %>

Comment: @Bharatsoni i actually tried CurrantGpa.new, but it threw an `undefined method 'current_gpas_path' for #<#<Class:0x5fb7340>:0x5f11ba8>` error at me. plus i need it as a variable so i can try to display it elsewhere without having to save it first.

Comment: @Bharatsoni and when i tried putting `@cgpa = CurrentGpa.new` into the index method, it gave me the same error in my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use: `<%= form_for @cgpa do |f| %>` this automatically tries to submit the form to the `CurrentGpasController create` action and for doing so it sends a request to `current_gpas_path`. So you don't have this path in routes that is why it throwing error. Either you can add routes for `CurrentGpa` like:

```
resources :current_gpas
```

or you can specify a path in the `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @cgpa, url: any_path do |f| %>
```

So this will submit your `form` to that `url` specified.

If you add the `current_gpas` routes then do create the `controller` and `action` to process your input.

And as mentioned in comments do add the `@cgpa = CurrentGpa.new` this in `index` action. The above will solve your error you are getting after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That solved the issue stated! I thought that the `*.new` method would have to be in it's own `new` action, but i suppose since it's all in the `main/index` view that it would need to be in the `index` action. Thankyou for explaining the process aswell

Comment: That depends on where you render your form